# jqgrid: How to render a field as link and open a jquery.dialog containing an ajax loaded edit page?

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid, dialog, edit

I'd like to render a field as a link and open a jquery dialog when a user clicks on the link.
Then, the dialog should ajax load an edit form and alert user if load fails...already exists some example? Some hint, suggestion, please?

I was thinking to re-use this code I found to open the edit dialog:

```
 function showDialog(url, strtitle) {

        var dialog = $('#dialog');

        if (!strtitle) strtitle = 'Errore apertura finestra!';

        $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
        $('#dialog').show();

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.9
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            title: strtitle,
            buttons: {
                'OK': function () {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about your field ?

Comment: @Heera: the field already contains an url. For example: 'http://mysite/mycontroller/action/my_id'. Field apart, I would try concentrate attention on the open dialog stuff, if possible of course.  If you think it's needed complete code, I can put here. I did not put just to simplify. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to know how to load data from server with ajax call and put it into a jquery dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but I hope this code snippet will give you an idea.

```
$(".editlink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var url=$(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(msg){
            if(msg.length>0)
            {
                $("<div id='newDynamicDiv'></div>").html(msg)
                .dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    minWidth: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Dialog Title',
                    hide: 'scale',
                    buttons: {
                    Update: function(e) {
                    // your code
                    },
                    Close: function() {
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function(e) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Empty Response");
            }
        },
        error:function(e){ alert("Failed!");}
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Heera. It is exactly what I need!
Unfortunately I did not succeed to get it work... I removed the first part of code until $.ajax and I tried to change url with a static one, but I always fall into Empty Response...